# How to check during compilation that GCC has at least C++17 running?

Tags: c++

How do I check during compilation that GCC (or any other compiler) has at least C++17 running? Can you give a minimal preprocessor snippet that emits an error if the version is below C++17?

I presume this can be built from `__cplusplus` and the `#error` directive.

Comment: Number to check has changed, you may print it out to know exactly.

Comment: _I presume this can be built from __cplusplus and the #error directive._ Correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```cpp
#if __cplusplus < 201703L
#error "C++17 or later is required!"
#endif
```

Comment: Thanks for verifying. I was facing a strange bug.